# Objective C forward declared protocol methods types are not available on Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, protocols

I have the following Objective C class header :

```
@protocol CustomKeyboard;
@class CustomKeyboardView;
@protocol CustomKeyboardViewProtocol <NSObject>

- (void)customKeyboardView:(UIView<CustomKeyboard> *)customKeyboard  numberPress:(UIButton *)sender;

@end

@protocol CustomKeyboard <NSObject>

@required

-(id)initWithDelegate:(id<CustomKeyboardViewProtocol>)delegate;
-(void)reload;

@property (nonatomic, weak) UITextField * textField;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<CustomKeyboardViewProtocol> delegate;

@end

@interface CustomKeyboardView : UIView <CustomKeyboard>
{
    IBOutlet UIView *keyboardView;
}

- (void)hide;
- (void)show;

@end
```

And this class in Swift is trying to adopt the protocol but I am getting an error about the types in the methods and autocomplete is gone:

```
extension MyViewController: CustomKeyboardViewProtocol {

    func customKeyboardView(_ customKeyboard: UIView!, numberPress sender: UIButton!) {
    }

}
```

The error says:

```
Candidate has non-matching type '(UIView!, UIButton!) -> ()'
```

Any clues if the error is because circular dependency in the protocols or is it about the types? I just updated to Xcode 9 and Swift 4, and updated to recommended settings, it used to work just fine.